# tengo un problema al tratar de guardar los datos de una jTable

Tags: java, jtable, prepared-statements

Tengo una JTable con algunos datos y quiero que cuando la edite se guarden directamente en mi base de datos cuando doy en el botón guardar, el problema es que no se guarda la última fila seleccionada, tengo que cambiar de fila y luego dar en guardar para que se guarde, como puedo solucionarlo. aquí esta el cóidgo:

```
private void jBEditarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    
    if(btEditar==false){
    tabla.setEnabled(true);
    jBEditar.setText("Guardar");
    jBEditar.setBackground(Color.red);
    jBActualizar.setText("Cancelar");
    jBActualizar.setBackground(Color.red);
    btEditar=true;
    }
   else if(btEditar){
    tabla.setColumnSelectionInterval(5, 4);
    jBEditar.setText("Editar");
    jBEditar.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    jBActualizar.setText("Actualizar");
    jBActualizar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    btEditar=false;
    tabla.setEnabled(false);
    guardar();
    actualizar();
    }
    
    
}


public void guardar(){

try {
    for(int i=0;i<tabla.getRowCount();i++){
    cs = cn.prepareCall("update gasto set valor='"+modelo.getValueAt(i,5)+"' where id_gasto ='"+ modelo.getValueAt(i, 0)+"';");
        System.out.println(""+info[4]);
    cs.execute();
   cs = cn.prepareCall("update gasto set plan='"+modelo.getValueAt(i,4)+"' where id_gasto ='"+ modelo.getValueAt(i, 0)+"';");
    cs.execute();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}



}
```

Comment: ya intentaste mandar tu actualizar a un hilo por ejemplo usando SwingUtilities?

Comment: Hola @rodolfo, hay alguna posibilidad de que **tabla.getRowCount()** te este dando un valor equivocado?